# Error in training opennmt - caffe2_detectron_ops.dll not found

Tags: pytorch, opennmt

I have torch 1.6 and python 3.8. When training OpenNMT, it throws the following error -

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Girish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\sitepackages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I checked the folder, the file is present there. I have tried uninstalling torch and reinstalling it, but no help.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: peterjc123, i installed intel-opnmp too, but it made no difference

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/35803#issuecomment-725285085

This answer worked for me.

Just deleting "**caffe2_detectron_ops.dl**l" from the path ("C:\Users\Girish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\sitepackages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops.dll")

Comment: Genius! How did you figure this out. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after deleting `caffe2_detectron_ops.dll`, it generated the same error for `caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll`, `caffe2_module_test_dynamic.dll`, `caffe2_observers.dll` and `cublas64_11.dll`.

So I followed [@youngwoon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65565829/13119339)'s step, **I deleted them all**. And everything works fine now.

> Honestly, this has a root cause and should be explained. But
> unfortunately, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pip install intel-openmp.

It worked for me

Comment: Hi Sushmitha. The creator of this question has specifically stated that they have tried to install this package and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find missing dependencies with various tools like [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) which is a rewrite of old Dependency Walker.

In my case the tool pointed to missing library libiomp5md.dll.

[image]

Installing intel-openmp as suggested by user @sushmitha resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

delete **caffe2_detectron_ops.dll** file from
C:\Users\ <your_user_name> \anaconda3\envs\ <your_environment> \Lib\site-packages\torch\lib

Answer (score 0):

Same error to me, but I think that deleting the items just disable the use of GPU use, this is not what I want.
I've tried, the error is gone, but the use os GPU too...

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

The return is False.

Reinstall torch works to me:

```
# pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html --user
# pip3 install torchaudio===0.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html --user
# pip3 install torchvision==0.11.2+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html --user
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).